# Prevent multiple row header from splitting when using xtabular

Tags: tables, page-breaking

Using the `xtab` package and the `xtabular` environment, I get my table header split when using several rows.

Example:

```
\noindent
\begin{center}
\small
\tablefirsthead{%
    \hline
   & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\
   \cline{2-9} 
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\
  \hline
  \hline}
\tablehead{%
  \multicolumn{9}{l}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\
  \cline{2-9} 
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\
  \hline
  \hline}
\tabletail{%
    \hline
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\
}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\topcaption{First Aggregation CFs table 1/2}
\label{first-aggregation-1}
\begin{xtabular}{|l||*{4}{l|}|*{4}{l|}}
    ClaConDef & 0.15 & 0.03 & 0.076 & 0.16 & - & - & - & - \\
    CovGenDev & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    SupUmbAct & - & - & - & - & 0.125 & - &  0.15 & - \\
    SmoSeaTra & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
 \end{xtabular}
\end{center}
```

Renders like this using pdflatex:

[image]

The second row of the header shouldn't be repeated and shouldn't be split from the first row as well. Any suggestion?

### ADDED

The undesired behavior can be obtained by running the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\textheight}\vspace*{-10\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
\small
\tablefirsthead{%
    \hline
   & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\
   \cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\
  \hline
  \hline}
\tablehead{%
  \multicolumn{9}{l}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\
  \cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\
  \hline
  \hline}
\tabletail{%
    \hline
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\
}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\topcaption{First Aggregation CFs table 1/2}
\label{first-aggregation-1}
\begin{xtabular}{|l||*{4}{l|}|*{4}{l|}}
    ClaConDef & 0.15 & 0.03 & 0.076 & 0.16 & - & - & - & - \\
    CovGenDev & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    SupUmbAct & - & - & - & - & 0.125 & - &  0.15 & - \\
    SmoSeaTra & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
 \end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm the bad behavior, even when `\\*` is used. It seems not to happen with `longtable` (it's not difficult to transform the `xtabular` environment into `longtable`).

Comment: I can't reproduce this bad behavior either (using the `article` document class). Please provide more information about your document, such as the document class, the page geometry, and (if possible) about how the material that precedes this `xtabular`.

Comment: I also cannot replicate the behavior using just any of the standard classes. Are you using other packages besides `xtab`? Providing a complete minimal working example (MWE) would be helpful.

Comment: I've added a way to get the undesired behavior; however, the `xtab` manual warns about starting an `xtabular` near the end of a page.

Comment: egreg's tip (using \\*) helped a lot. I can't reproduce the described behaviour using \\* . Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a longtable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\textheight}\vspace*{-8\baselineskip}

{\fontsize{8.5}{8.6}\selectfont\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{ |l||*4{l|}|*4{l|} }
\caption{First Aggregation CFs table 1/2}\label{first-aggregation-1}\\\hline
   & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\\cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{9}{l}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\\cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\\hline\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
    ClaConDef & 0.15 & 0.03 & 0.076 & 0.16 & - & - & - & - \\
    CovGenDev & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    SupUmbAct & - & - & - & - & 0.125 & - &  0.15 & - \\
    SmoSeaTra & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\end{longtable}%
}

foo
\end{document}
```

with the package [ltablex](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex) instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\textheight}\vspace*{-10\baselineskip}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l||*4{l|}|*4{l|} }
\caption{First Aggregation CFs table 1/2}\label{first-aggregation-1}\\\hline
   & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\\cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{9}{l}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\\hline
  & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{NoExtKnowSrc} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{UserMngmt} \\\cline{2-9}
  & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe & StSeCo & SeLoCo & SeAb & SeRe \\\hline\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{r}{\small\sl continued on next page}\\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
    ClaConDef & 0.15 & 0.03 & 0.076 & 0.16 & - & - & - & - \\
    CovGenDev & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    SupUmbAct & - & - & - & - & 0.125 & - &  0.15 & - \\
    SmoSeaTra & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
 \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

However, it makes no real sense to use a tabularx when not using a X column.

Comment: ltablex is not installed in my system and \\* tip worked well for me. Anyway, could you point me to some reference about X columns? I can't see anything about it in xtab documentation. Thank you.

Comment: @Apiman: I added a solution with longtable, see my answer